# How to overlapping the different information in the PCA plot?

Tags: r, visualization, pca

I tried to draw the modified PCA plot representing two types of categories. 
For example, I want to draw PCA with 1) PCA ellipse based on Kingdom, 2) PCA sample points colored with Class variable. 
Here is the example dataset.

```r
require(ggplot2)
require(ggfortify)

set.seed(1)
df <- structure(list(Sample = c("cat", "dog", "rabbit", "chicken", "duck", "butterfly", "ladybug", "rose", "lily", "iris", "maple tree", "pinetree", "ginkgo"), 
                     Class = c("mammalia", "mammalia", "mammalia", "bird", "bird", "insect", "insect", "flower", "flower", "flower", "tree", "tree", "tree"), 
                     Kingdom = c("animalia", "animalia", "animalia", "animalia", "animalia", "animalia", "animalia", "plantae", "plantae", "plantae", "plantae", "plantae", "plantae")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
rownames(df)<-df[,1]
df[,1]<-NULL

for(i in 3:20){
  df[,i]<-sample(100, size=nrow(df), replace=TRUE)
}
df[,c(3:20)]<-log(df[,c(3:20)]+1, base=2)

df #I ommitted the value from v13 to v20 for simplicity
              Class  Kingdom       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10      V11      V12
cat        mammalia animalia 6.108524 5.781360 5.087463 5.357552 4.247928 5.614710 5.000000 5.129283 5.321928 6.303781
dog        mammalia animalia 5.321928 6.228819 6.409391 5.491853 4.523562 6.491853 4.169925 3.459432 4.643856 4.523562
rabbit     mammalia animalia 1.000000 3.000000 5.169925 4.700440 6.303781 4.584963 6.209453 1.000000 5.754888 6.149747
chicken        bird animalia 5.129283 6.209453 6.149747 6.149747 6.044394 6.409391 6.459432 5.459432 6.539159 4.857981
duck           bird animalia 6.459432 6.321928 6.228819 5.321928 6.149747 4.906891 6.392317 5.906891 6.442943 5.247928
butterfly    insect animalia 5.459432 6.426265 5.426265 5.700440 6.459432 3.807355 6.507795 4.754888 5.357552 5.954196
ladybug      insect animalia 3.906891 5.247928 5.285402 5.426265 6.149747 4.523562 5.614710 4.000000 6.614710 5.554589
rose         flower  plantae 6.375039 6.491853 4.392317 2.807355 6.247928 6.554589 6.022368 5.882643 6.392317 6.087463
lily         flower  plantae 5.906891 5.247928 4.857981 4.643856 6.357552 4.857981 6.569856 4.906891 6.507795 6.442943
iris         flower  plantae 5.700440 5.129283 4.392317 5.044394 6.658211 5.614710 6.599913 4.643856 5.169925 6.643856
maple tree     tree  plantae 6.614710 6.491853 5.491853 3.906891 3.807355 5.087463 5.930737 5.426265 5.459432 6.169925
pinetree       tree  plantae 6.426265 5.491853 6.459432 1.584963 5.357552 5.523562 5.700440 5.614710 1.000000 6.643856
ginkgo         tree  plantae 4.459432 6.321928 6.149747 5.523562 6.491853 4.459432 6.554589 6.266787 4.906891 5.700440
```

After instruct the dataset, I drew PCA plot using autoplot

```r
pca_df<-prcomp(df[,-c(1,2)], scale.=TRUE)
autoplot(pca_df)
autoplot(pca_df, data=df, colour='Kingdom', frame.type='norm')
```

[image]

In this plot, I want to overlap the color according to the Class

```r
pca_df<-prcomp(df[,-c(1,2)], scale.=TRUE)
autoplot(pca_df)
autoplot(pca_df, data=df, colour='Class')
```

[image]

In summary, I want to use the ellipse representation from Kingdom variable, and coloring with Class variable.
How can I combine different representation in one PCA plot?

---

Additional trial 
I tried drawing PCA plot using other package (factoextra), but it show same result.

```r
require (factoextra)

fviz_pca_ind(pca_df,
             col.ind=df$Kingdom,
             addEllipses = TRUE,
             col.ind.sup=df$Class,
             repel=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `frame.colour` for the ellipses and the `colour` for the points:

```r
autoplot(pca_df, data=df, colour='Class', frame.type='norm', frame.colour = "Kingdom")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your prompt and accurate answer! May I ask one more question? Do you know how to control the transparency of boundray of each groups of Kingdom? The points contained in duplicated are hard to distinguish..

Comment: @Ssong have you tried adding `alpha = 0.1` as a parameter to `autoplot`?

Comment: Yes. But it controlled the transparency of points, not boundary area..

Comment: Oh, I see. ```frame.alpha=0.1``` is the proper method for boundary color! Thank you for your hint!!

Comment: Sir, I have a question. While I generate the figure, I found that there were some mismatches in the legend. As you can see, animalia and plantae are Kingdom, not Class. But those two features were contained in the Class legend and occupy the unnecessary colors. How can I eliminate them and assign correct colors?